Performing hypothesis testing on Regression coefficients
Let say we have an estimated regression equation with multiple explanatory variables, and estimated values of coefficients are ${\beta}_1, {\beta}_2, ..., {\beta}_p$
Now I want to test the null that ${\beta}_1 = 0, {\beta}_2 = 0, ..., {\beta}_m = 0$ and ${\beta}_{m+1} \neq 0, {\beta}_{m+1} \neq 0, ..., {\beta}_p \neq 0$
One possible way is to perform individual t-test. But I wonder if it is right approach as in that case I am not performing the test jointly.
Given that jointly all beta coefficients follow Normal distribution for large sample size, I can I design the null hypothesis to jointly perform test?
Also, how exactly I can prove that performing individual t-test is not optimal?


We should use a different notation for estimated parameters $\hat\beta_1, \hat\beta_2, \dots, \hat\beta_p$ to avoid confusion with unknown parameters $\beta_1, \beta_2, \dots, \beta_p$.
Usually, we cannot include $\beta_k\neq 0$ in the null hypothesis, because there are no useful tests for that.
Thus, your null hypothesis should be stated as $H_0: \beta_1=\beta_2=\dots=\beta_m=0$.
The most common joint test in this situation is the $F$-test, where residual of squares are compared between the model with $H_0$ constraint and the model without such a constraint.
This is not the only possible test, but it has some desirable properties.
Technically, doing individual tests is not necessarily wrong, but the dependency and the overall level is harder to be taken account of.

